# Activity cannot set a Variable defined within its scope?

Tags: .net, variables, workflow-foundation-4

This one is making me scratch my head, and I'm wondering if I am understanding this correctly.

I'm trying to define a Variable within an Activity that can be used by child Activities.  The Parent should be able to set a value in this Variable at runtime.

Here's the stripped down Parent class:

```
public sealed class Parent : NativeActivity, IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Collection<Child> Children { get; private set; }
    private CompletionCallback<string> _cc;
    private Variable<int> _index;
    public Collection<Variable> Variables { get; private set; }        
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new Collection<Child>();
        _index = new Variable<int>();
        _cc = new CompletionCallback<string>(OnComplete);
        Variables = new Collection<Variable>();
    }
    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(_index);
        metadata.SetVariablesCollection(Variables);
    }
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        _index.Set(context, 0);
        var input = Variables.First(x => x.Name == "ThisIsTheVariable");
        input.Set(context, "This is the Value");
        context.ScheduleActivity(Children[0], _cc);
    }
    private void OnComplete(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance instance, string result)
    {
        var index = _index.Get(context) + 1;
        _index.Set(context, index);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        if (index < Children.Count)
            context.ScheduleActivity(Children[index], _cc);
    }
    Activity IActivityTemplateFactory.Create(System.Windows.DependencyObject target)
    {
        var retval = new Parent();
        retval.Variables.Add(new Variable<string>("ThisIsTheVariable"));
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Now, if I add this to a workflow and run it, I get the following highly ironic exception:

> **Activity '1.1: Parent' cannot access
>   this variable because it is declared
>   at the scope of activity '1.1:
>   Parent'.  An activity can only access
>   its own implementation variables.**

The problem is that I need to pass a value to my child Activities that they can bind to at design time.  That means that whatever holds the value must be visible within the intellisense of the child Activities.  The only ways I can think of doing this is to define a Variable like above, or create an OutArgument on the parent.  The second option flat out sucks.

***How can I get around this?***

---

***Edit***

Tried to do a little trickery with the variable that didn't work.

I declared a variable within my Parent:

```
// declaration
private Variable<string> _text;

// in ctor I create it
_text = new Variable<string>(InputName);

// in CacheMetadata I declare it an implementation variable
metadata.AddImplementationVariable(_text);

// in IActivityTemplateFactory.Create I add it to Variables
var retval = new Parent()
{
    Input = new InArgument<string>()
};
retval.Variables.Add(retval._text);
return retval;
```

This works up until execution time.  The variable appears in the design surface and my child activities can bind against it.  But I still can't touch it at runtime.  I can attempt to do this two ways:

```
// set text via the implementation variable
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    _text.Set(context, "DERP");
    context.ScheduleActivity(Children[0], _cc);
}
```

This doesn't throw, but the child activities never see `DERP`, as the instance of the Variable they are bound against apparently isn't the same as `_text` as the binding evaluates to `null`.

The second way is to grab the Variable from the Variables collection and set it.

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
    Variables.First().Set(context, "DERP");
    context.ScheduleActivity(Children[0], _cc);
}
```

This results in the same exception being thrown.  I can't touch a variable defined within my own scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [ActivityAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activityaction.aspx) to wrap the child activities that need access to the same variable and pass it through there. The variable itself needs to be added using [NativeActivityMetadata.AddImplementationVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivitymetadata.addimplementationvariable.aspx) to the parent activity itself can manipulate it like you are doing. That is the way activities like the ForEach are doing it as well.

See my blog post [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/04/05/scheduling-child-activities-with-input-parameters.aspx) for more details.

Comment: ActivityAction is all fine and well **for a single child**, but how do you do this when you have a **collection of children**?  I'm trying to avoid requiring the user drop a Sequence in, as most likely they will always be adding more than one child.

Comment: The convention is to have a single child and let the user add a Sequence when needed, just like the ForEach etc. But there is nothing preventing you from already doing that yourself in an IActivityTemplate or the related designer.

Comment: @Maurice: I could see a converter working to wrap an Activity in an ActivityAction, but how should the Variable be bound to the Argument of the AA?  Again, I definitely could replace the collection with a single child, but since I fully expect to have more than one child, it seems... lame to do that.

Comment: @Maurice: I suppose I could have a single child, make it a Sequence, then bind directly to its collection instead of my own, but that seems a bit odd to do.  Effective from the designer standpoint, but hacky from a code standpoint.

Comment: You pass the value of the variable as a parameter to ScheduleAction, the child doesn't use the original variable. The parameter shows up to all childeren just like another Variable or InArgument. So as fasr as the data is concerned it doesn't matter if there is a single child or a Sequence.

Comment: @Maurice: But the children have to bind to *something* in the design surface.  I could change the collection from Activites to ActivityActions, but there would have to be some kind of conversion.  That conversion would have to create the Argument variable that the child activities would bind against.  Any examples of that?

Comment: @Will: Not quite sure I understand. Is this an existing activity you are upgrading and you are worried about the current workflows? As far as I know there is no way of converting the activity without editing the XAML beforehand using an XML API. Or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: @Maurice: I'm trying to create it.  My Parent activity has a number of child `NativeActivity<object>`s.  Realized I **cannot** wrap in a `Sequence` because I must run each child and get its return value.  The disconnect in my mind is how to provide the `InArgument` that each child needs to bind against in the designer.  I cannot provide a `Variable` it seems, as scoping rules prevent me from accessing the variable.  Cannot wrap children in ActivityFuncs<In,Out> as how do they bind against the Argument of the AF at design time?

Comment: @Will: Right I get it but I am afraid I have never tried something like that. I guess I would try something like model it with a Sequence as a child in the designer but never actually execute the sequence and instead execute its children directly using an ActivityFunc. Basically just changing the ActivityFunc.Handler for each activity. Now I have never tried it so if that is really gone work...

Comment: "The convention is to have a single child and let the user add a Sequence when needed."  In this scenario, it appears that is the only way to design it.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since I was looking for a solution, maybe someone else is still looking too...

I found a way to do this using the context.DataContext.

In your original example, replace;

```
var input = Variables.First(x => x.Name == "ThisIsTheVariable"); 
input.Set(context, "This is the Value");
```

with;

```
var input = context.DataContext.GetProperties()["ThisIsTheVariable"];
input.SetValue(context.DataContext, "This is the Value");
```

Comment: I'll try this.  I have been getting around it by using ActivityAction<T> etal and setting their Arguments.  If this works, damnit, WF4 team!  Good job with the error messages!

Comment: :( the instance returned by `DataContext.GetProperties()[]` is *not* the same variable declared in the variable collection, and they are not available at design time.  So this isn't a solution-solution, but more of a hack-solution.