# Scheduling child activity that implements an interface with input parameters

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, argument-passing, workflow-activity, correlation

```
public sealed class Parent : NativeActivity
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Childrens = new Collection<Activity>();
        Variables = new Collection<Variable>();

        _currentActivityIndex = new Variable<int>();
        CurrentCustomTypeInstance= new Variable<MyCustomType>();
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Collection<Activity> Childrens { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        _currentActivityIndex.Set(context, 0);
        context.ScheduleActivity(FirstActivity, Callback);
    }

    private void Callback(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedInstance, MyCustomType customTypeInstance)
    {
        CurrentCustomTypeInstance.Set(context, customTypeInstance);
        ScheduleNextChildren(context, completedInstance);
    }

    private void ScheduleNextChildren(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedInstance)
    {
        int nextActivityIndex = _currentActivityIndex.Get(context) + 1;
        if (nextActivityIndex >= Childrens.Count)
            return;

        Activity nextActivity = Childrens[nextActivityIndex];

        IFoo nextActivityAsIFoo = nextActivity as IFoo;
        if (nextActivityAsIFoo != null)
        {
            var currentCustomTypeInstance = CurrentCustomTypeInstance.Get(context);
            // HERE IS MY EXCEPTION
            nextActivityAsIFoo.FooField.Set(context, currentCustomTypeInstance);
        }

        context.ScheduleActivity(nextActivity);
        _currentActivityIndex.Set(context, nextActivityIndex);

    }
}
```

And in register metadata:

```
metadata.SetChildrenCollection(Childrens);
```

I've already read http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/04/05/scheduling-child-activities-with-input-parameters.aspx but in my case, parent does not know the child activity

*Edit*

Similar to: [Activity cannot set a Variable defined within its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285239/activity-cannot-set-a-variable-defined-within-its-scope)

```
Activity '1.1: Parent' cannot access this variable because it is declared at the scope
of activity '1.1: Parent'. An activity can only access its own implementation variables.
```

But in my case, I don't need to get the return value, so, hope to be easier. Just need to pass FooField implicitly instead of leting it to flow author.
I need to do it implicitly! If it doesn't work at all, I will go with NativeActivityContext Properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Looking at the Maurice's blog I got inspired to do it

**Workflow**(very very simple!)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.Childrens.Add(new FooWriter());
    parent.Childrens.Add(new FooFormater());
    parent.Childrens.Add(new FooWriter());

    WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(parent);
    Console.Read();
}
```

**Output**

```
What's the Foo name?
Implicit FTW!
Im a custom Foo Handler, my Foo name is: Implicit FTW!
Im a custom Foo Handler, my Foo name is: IMPLICIT FTW!
```

**Implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WorkflowConsoleApplication2
{
// Parent class that creates a Foo and passes it to their childrens
public sealed class Parent : NativeActivity
{
    private Variable<int> _currentActivityIndex;
    private Variable<Foo> _currentFoo;

    public Parent()
    {
        Childrens = new Collection<Activity>();
        _executionChildrens = new Collection<Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>>>();

        _currentActivityIndex = new Variable<int>();
        _currentFoo = new Variable<Foo>();
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Collection<Activity> Childrens { get; set; }
    private Collection<Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>>> _executionChildrens;

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What's the Foo name?");
        _currentFoo.Set(context, new Foo { Name = Console.ReadLine() });

        _currentActivityIndex.Set(context, 0);
        ScheduleNextChildren(context, null);
    }

    private void ScheduleNextChildren(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completedInstance)
    {
        int currentActivityIndex = _currentActivityIndex.Get(context);
        if (currentActivityIndex >= Childrens.Count)
            return;

        Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>> nextActivity = _executionChildrens[currentActivityIndex];

        if (IsFooHandler(nextActivity))
        {
            context.ScheduleAction(nextActivity.Item2, _currentFoo.Get(context),
                ScheduleNextChildren);
        }
        else
        {
            context.ScheduleActivity(nextActivity.Item1,
                ScheduleNextChildren);
        }

        _currentActivityIndex.Set(context, currentActivityIndex + 1);

    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.SetArgumentsCollection(metadata.GetArgumentsWithReflection());

        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(_currentActivityIndex);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(_currentFoo);

        RegisterChildrens(metadata, Childrens);
        // remove "base.Cachemetadata" to "Childrens collection" doesn't become a child   again        }

    public void RegisterChildrens(NativeActivityMetadata metadata, IEnumerable<Activity> childrens)
    {
        foreach (Activity child in childrens)
        {
            IFooHandler childAsIFooHandler = child as IFooHandler;
            if (childAsIFooHandler != null)
            {
                ActivityAction<Foo> childsWrapperAction = new ActivityAction<Foo>();

                var activityToActionBinderArgument = new DelegateInArgument<Foo>();
                childsWrapperAction.Argument =  activityToActionBinderArgument;
                childAsIFooHandler.Foo =        activityToActionBinderArgument;

                childsWrapperAction.Handler = child;

                metadata.AddDelegate(childsWrapperAction);
                _executionChildrens.Add(new Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>>(child, childsWrapperAction));
            }
            else
            {
                metadata.AddChild(child);
                _executionChildrens.Add(new Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>>(child, null));
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsFooHandler(Tuple<Activity, ActivityAction<Foo>> activity)
    {
        return activity.Item2 != null;
    }
}

// samples of Foo handlers
public class FooWriter : CodeActivity, IFooHandler
{
    /// When FooWriter is direct child of "Parent" this argument is passed implicitly
    public InArgument<Foo> Foo { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Im a custom Foo Handler, my Foo name is: {0}", Foo.Get(context).Name);
    }
}

public class FooFormater : CodeActivity, IFooHandler
{
    public InArgument<Foo> Foo { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        Foo foo = Foo.Get(context);
        foo.Name = foo.Name.ToUpper();
    }
}

// sample classes
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooHandler
{
    InArgument<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}
}
```

If anyone know how to do it in a better way please fell free to tell me. I will also need to pass the values to nested activities

Comment: Aaaah, I see what you did thar.  Instead of doing this within the designer using some kind of converter, you are taking advantage of CacheMetadata (which is called on every change within the design surface) to create and register your ActivityActions.  Very clever.  It does seem *slightly* hacky (two collections, multiple references to the same child), but it should definitely work and be much easier to accomplish.  I likes.

Comment: Thanks for comenting. I think that's possible to implement with one collection too. What do you mean with 'some kind of converter'. I'm still looking for alternative ways of doing that.

Comment: By using a [value converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx) that converts an Activity dropped on the designer into an ActivityAction during the binding process.  The problem with that is how to determine, within the converter, what exactly to do.  There are lots of possible activity delegates to choose from, and the question of how to name each argument in the delegate, and how the dropped activity binds against them... lots of questions I haven't answered yet.  That's why this is clever in its hackiness.

Comment: Bless you, sir. I got gray hair trying to make this scenario work.

Comment: Don't know if you are still around, but do you see any problems with not including a call to `base.CacheMetadata`? I know it won't work if you do, but are there any problems with this?

Comment: I don't understand your question... `base.CacheMetadata` was already removed so `Collection<Activity> Childrens` don't become a duplicate execution collection... it was replaced by the properly cached `_executionChildrens`

Comment: Thanks, having checked the code of `NativeActivity.CacheMetadata` and comparing with your code it seems you that all fields are being populated correctly, and so calling `base.CacheMetadata` is not needed.