# Passing workflow instance Id when using new WorkflowApplication()

Tags: .net, wpf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a workflow service host. In workflow service, I have an activity ExecuteCounterActivity

```
public sealed class ExecuteCounterActivity : CodeActivity
{

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var workflowInstanceId = context.WorkflowInstanceId;
        var workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new CounterActivity());
        workflowApplication.Run();
    }
}
```

the workflow instanceid = "06DD16A5-D4B2-4907-A6FF-CA6021E66D75" when I get by code:  **context.WorkflowInstanceId**

In ExecuteCounterActivity , I new a Workflow application **CounterActivity**. Therefore, in CounterActivity. I get workflowInstaceId, it will return a new instance Id: "444FEC86-62C1-4AAC-A857-9B9559051E63"

**My expectation**: the workflow instanceId in CounterActivity is same as with instanceId in ExecuteCounterActivity.

For now, I don't have any solution for that, so can someone show me the solution for resolving my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a diferent approach, using composition activities or scheduling it like:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    context.ScheduleActivity(new CounterActivity());
}
```

[Custom Composite Activity @msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd177566.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Scheduling Child Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401760/scheduling-child-activity-that-implements-an-interface-with-input-parameters)